# how to create a file applicationhost.config

Tags: iis, iis-express

`HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found` - I can not deal with this error handle. I know that I have to edit `applicationhost.config`, but I deleted it because it edited the badly and I could not fix it. I tried to fix `IIS 10` express in the control panel
I tried to reinstall IIS 10 express
still I do not have a file `applicationhost.config`

how to create a default `applicationhost.config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a copy located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationHost.config`. You can use it to replace the corrupt one.